# Why do my vertices keep snapping to the center?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices, mirror

Whenever I try to move vertices that aren't connected to a mesh (but are still registered as the same object) they snap to the centre and I don't even have snapping on or auto snap, what is going on and how do I fix it?

This is what I did, I got a vertex point and duplicated it with shift+D
and when I extruded it behaved weirdly. But when I connected that piece to the main mesh it acts fine. Can anyone explain?
(Btw I have a mirror modifier I haven't applied yet)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem! I accidentally used a mirror modifier AND the mesh symmetry option (in the upper right-hand corner next to options) so, I turned that off and left the modifier on, so now it works.